# Comments Flags declined

Tags: discussion

I was reading lot of Q&As in Our site for learning, editing it, voting if it’s really good & flagging noisy comments like +1, Thanks, Cool kind of stuffs as a cleanup.

But want to understand why my comment flags (no longer needed) were [declined](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/72613?group=4&status=3)?

[image]

Comment: FYI others can't see your flagging history, so the link you provided is inaccessible. If you are comfortable with it, you might want to provide a screenshot of the case.

Comment: @moe added screenshot

Comment: Can't tell about how the flagging's declining process was handled in more details, but when flagging "thanks"-comments, they should go under the category "Too chatty". [It is a valid reason to flag a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged). If other categories were used, it might explain the declines.

Comment: @moe the flag options are clubbed as single option now called “no longer needed” which includes obsolete, chatty or otherwise unnecessary.. the same one I raised.. anyway I could not raise again. Someone can clean those..

Comment: I see. Well, this goes beyond the judgement of a mere normal user just like I am as well. Would also gladly hear the comments of others.